# Error inflating class fragment when I try to run the app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I get this error when i try to run my android app:

```
                                                                               Process: com.example.ronen.sunplantnew, PID: 28608
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ronen.sunplantnew/com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
                                                                               at com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:59)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
                                                                               at com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The main activity java file (MainActivity.java)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements HomeScreen.OnFragmentInteractionListener, LightTest.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

the main activity xml file (activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.MainActivity">
<fragment class="com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.HomeScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeScreen java file (HomeScreen.java):

```
public class HomeScreen extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


private Button newTest;
private Button lastTests;
private Button plants;
private Button about;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public HomeScreen() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment HomeScreen.
 */
public static HomeScreen newInstance() {
    HomeScreen fragment = new HomeScreen();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    newTest=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newTest);
    lastTests=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lastTests);
    plants=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plants);
    about=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.about);

    newTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toLightTest();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

public void toLightTest(){
    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new LightTest();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

HomeScreen xml file (fragment_home_screen.xml):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.HomeScreen">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/sun_plant"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About"
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Tests"
    android:id="@+id/lastTests"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newTest"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New LightTest"
    android:id="@+id/newTest"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Plants Info"
    android:id="@+id/plants"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lastTests"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/newTest"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/newTest"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
```

What do i need to do to fix this error?

Comment: What is the name of the main activity file? Also, post code of the HomeScreen class.

Comment: There is a problem with HomeScreen.  Please post the full error, not just the first line.  Also post the content of HomeScreen.

Comment: ok, i post the full classes and errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find `newTest` in your `Activity`, but it's inside `HomeScreen`.

Try this instead:

***HomeScreen.java***

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);

    newTest = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.newTest);
    lastTests = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.lastTests);
    plants = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.plants);
    about=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.about);

    newTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toLightTest();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you're also trying to grab the views in your fragment before they actually exist. `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView`, and it's `onCreateView` that inflates the views. They don't exist before that, so `Fragment.onCreate` will never be able to actually do anything with views. It's more for setting up internal state based on the parameter bundle passed in.